# How to keep the serial number to stay with the sequence in a html table with dynamic add/remove?

Tags: jquery, dom

I have a table like below and its rows can be added and removed by using the add/remove buttons.

```
<table class="dynatable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><button class="add">Add</button></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Col 3</th>
            <th>Col 4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="prototype">
            <td><input type="text" name="id[]" value="0" class="id" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name[]" value="" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="col4[]" value="" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="col3[]" value="" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The first column in the table contains the serial number. But when the rows are removed in between it is losing its sequence.

For example if there are rows 5 rows with serial sequence of 1,2,3,4,5

If the row with the serial number of 3 is removed the serial number will lose the sequence to 1,2,4,5

But I want the serial numbers in the first column to keep the sequence like 1,2,3,4 after removing a row from a five rows

And if I add 5 rows and removed all the rows and start to add rows again. the sequence starts from 6 instead of 1.

How can I do it using jQuery?

Comment: Could the ID be changed or is it always a sequence?

Comment: it should always stay with 1, 2, 3 sequence even when the rows in between are removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recalculate the whole sequence when something is removed like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/5HCVX/16/

```
function recalcId(){
    $.each($("table tr.item"),function (i,el){
        $(this).find("td:first input").val(i + 1); // Simply couse the first "prototype" is not counted in the list
    })
}
```

​Also when something is removed just to decresse the `id`

Comment: It works when i just remove the rows in between but when I remove all rows and start adding rows once again, it loses the sequence and starts from the last serial number of the previous sequence. how to retain the sequence in this case ?

Comment: Yeap...it works for me too ;) I liked a wrong jquery version and that was the problem. now changed to 1.7

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            var id = 0;

            // Add button functionality
            $("table.dynatable button.add").click(function() {
                id++;
                var master = $(this).parents("table.dynatable");

                // Get a new row based on the prototype row
                var prot = master.find(".prototype").clone();
                prot.attr("class", id + " item")
                prot.find(".id").attr("value", id);

                master.find("tbody").append(prot);
                prot.append('<td><button class="remove">Remove</button></td>');
            });

            // Remove button functionality
            $("table.dynatable button.remove").live("click", function() {
                $(this).parents("tr").remove();
                id--; //simon was missing this now it's perfect
                recalcId();
            });
        });

function recalcId(){
    $.each($("table tr.item"),function (i,el){
        $(this).find("td:first input").val(i + 1); // Simply couse the first "prototype" is not counted in the list
    })
}
​
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply take the resulting array after editing records and in a cycle to set new records IDs. Do you can get array of records from this table?

Answer (score 0):

I think the size() function may be useful here.  Taking your code, I added the line

```
id = $('table.dynatable tbody tr').size() -1
```

. . . to the "Remove button" functionality.  So the whole JS is now:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            var id = 0;

            // Add button functionality
            $("table.dynatable button.add").click(function() {
                id++;
                var master = $(this).parents("table.dynatable");

                // Get a new row based on the prototype row
                var prot = master.find(".prototype").clone();
                prot.attr("class", id)
                prot.find(".id").attr("value", id);

                master.find("tbody").append(prot);
                prot.append('<td><button class="remove">Remove</button></td>');
            });

            // Remove button functionality
            $("table.dynatable button.remove").live("click", function() {
                $(this).parents("tr").remove();
                id = $('table.dynatable tbody tr').size() -1;
            });
        });
```